# Async false in ajax requests using jquery

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I have a calendar control on my site. It fetches some availability data from the server using some ajax request. 
Here is the code -

```
var monthlyBookingDetails = getBooking(month, year);//getBooking is ajax function
//rest of code
```

Here in the `getBooking` function if i make async: false, it works but browser is blocked till the ajax request is serviced.

So I thought of a turn around as -

```
while(monthlyBookingDetails.length <= 0){//busy waiting}
```

But I feel this is not the proper way, so just want to understand what is the correct way to do busy waiting and block the following lines to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this code, you're right:

```
while(monthlyBookingDetails.length <= 0){//busy waiting}
```

That says "do an infinite loop until `monthlyBookingDetails` is less than or equal to `0`". Deliberately introducing infinite loops (even if they will *eventually* be broken) is not likely to be a sensible move. Especially since, if your AJAX fails, the infinite loop won't be broken.

The correct way to do this is to embrace the asynchronous way. That means **callbacks**. That means supplying a function that is called when your asynchronous code is complete.

So inside `getBooking` you would do this:

```
function getBooking(month, year, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        /* all your settings */
        success: function() {
            callback(); // call the callback function
        }
    });
}
```

You would then call the function like this:

```
getBooking(month, year, function() {
    /* your code here */
});
```

This pattern will probably be familiar to you if you have used jQuery much. It is present in all kinds of asynchronous actions, e.g. AJAX and animation.

You will almost certainly want to pass data to your callback. You do this in the normal fashion: `callback(data)` and `getBooking(month, year, function(data) {`.

Comment: Thanks!!, I would place a callback in the complete : function(){} to avoid infinite loop